# wpdb update add current timestamp not working

Tags: database, wpdb, date

So using the $wpdb->update to add some data to a custom table, trying to add the current timestamp but it's not saving the right stuff(0000-00-00 00:00:00 this is saved).

overview code

```
  $wpdb->update('mytable',
      array(
          'value' => 'hello world', 
          'edit'  => date("Y-m-d h:i:s") //saves 0000-00-00 00:00:00
      ),
      array(
          'option_name' => 'the row'
      ), 
      array('%s, %s')
  );
```

Comment: Try: `date( "Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime( time() );`

Comment: @Sormano `time()` returns an integer, not a string.

Comment: You're right, used strtotime() to many times... right code: `date( "Y-m-d h:i:s", time() );`

Comment: still saving 0000-00-00 00:00:00.... db col(`edit` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

Comment: found the issue %d should be %s. but I see that it saves the server time not the current timezone

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You seemed to have solved everything but the issue with the time:

> found the issue %d should be %s. but I see that it saves the server
> time not the current timezone

[WordPress has a number of date/time related functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time). In this case, it sounds like what you need is [`current_time()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/), which...

> Returns the blog's current local time in one of two formats, either
> MySQL's timestamp data type format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) or the
> Unix timestamp format (i.e. epoch).

So what you should need is:

```
$wpdb->update(
      'mytable',
      array(
          'value' => 'hello world', 
          'edit'  => current_time( 'mysql' )
      ),
      array(
          'option_name' => 'the row'
      ), 
      array('%s, %s')
);
```